# Exporting data from R to spreadsheet

Tags: r, quantmod

I am trying to export stock prices from R to a spreadsheet. Everything is exporting OK except for the date. These are the commands I am using.

Edit: Just to confirm the date is not been exported at all.

```
library(quantmod)
library(dataframes2xls)
getSymbols("GOOG", from = "2010-01-01", to = "2012-06-30")
write.xls(GOOG, "C:/goog.xls")
```

Comment: Please show a sample of the output file so we can understand how the date is wrong.

Comment: Sorry David, I didn't explain it properly. The date is not been exported at all just the rest of the data (opening, closing prices e.t.c. Do you want me to share the spreadsheet somewhere?

Comment: Convert to data.frame (as I've shown) or force rownames (as Garrett suggested).  Now that edited your question and shown the `dataframes2xls` package use, it is even *more obvious* that you need a dataframe.  Most of us use `write.xls` from the `gdata` package which came first, or one of the two Java-based packages.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, I added the `require("dataframes2xls")` because that's what `sos::findFn("write.xls")` turned up.  The OP should change it if using **`gdata`**

Comment: @GSee: That is rather objectionable editing on your part.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, **`gdata`** doesn't have a `write.xls` function, but you're free to object ;-)

Comment: Hah. Should have remembered. There are two distinct Perl modules, and Greg only deployed the reader.  Folks like him and myself would never understand why you'd want to export to xls ;-)  So I guess I use xlsx there....

Comment: Lastly, and while we are publicly debating style: Please switch from require-with-quotes to just using library.  Quotes are not needed, and require is obfuscation as library is the common command.

Comment: Hah, I've very recently switch from library without quotes to require with quotes because I assumed it avoided some extra `deparse(substitute())` stuff.  Will change back.  Thanks!

Comment: Did you microbenchmark? Do you _really_ expect it to matter? As in _REALLY_ ? ;-)

Comment: Why don't you use write.csv instead?  works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to include `row.names=TRUE` in your `write.xls` call

```
write.xls(GOOG, "C:/goog.xls", row.names=TRUE)
```

Comment: Getting a different error now.                                      Error in write.xls(GOOG, "C:/goog.xls", row.names = TRUE) : 
unused argument(s) (row.names = TRUE)

Comment: @user1016078, Are you using `write.xls` from the **dataframes2xls** package?  If so, it certainly has a `row.names` argument, and the code above worked for me (although I used a different file path as I am on linux)

Comment: When I type **library(dataframes2xls)** I get this error **The following object(s) are masked from ‘package:xlsReadWrite’:

    write.xls**. Then when I try and export I get this error **"Does 'python' exist, and is it in the path?**. I am on Windows. Maybe that is the problem. :)

Comment: That is why it is important for you to make your code reproducible.  Read through the comments in your question. See? we had to guess which package `write.xls` comes from.  I cannot find the **xlsReadWrite** package, but I found the documentation online (you should be able to see it for yourself in `?write.xls`).  It uses `rowNames` instead of `row.names`.  So, do this `write.xls(GOOG, "C:/goog.xls", rowNames=TRUE)`

Comment: Working perfectly now. Thanks very much your help.